# How to override a specific text value in a paragraph of the textbox

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver

I want to change the value of the text. But the text is in middle (4th line) of the paragraph of a textbox.  Can anyone please guide me how to identify the text and how to change it.

Note : I cant use clear() & sendkeys() methods in this case. Because rest all other data is changing dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that by "textbox" you mean `input type="text"`.

You need to:

1. Get the `input type="text"` element form the DOM.
2. Get it's value (the text).
3. Use `.replace()`.
4. Put the replaced string back in.

HTML

```
<input id="myInput" type="text" value="This is my text" />
```

JS

```
var myInput = document.getElementById("myInput")
var myText = myInput.value.replace("my", "your");
myInput.value = myText;
```

"This is my text" will change to "This is your text".

Answer (score 0):

Using selenium and java, you can do it like this:

```
    //load the original text
    String originalText = driver.findElement(By.id(inputId)).getAttribute("value");
   // replace
    String newText = originalText.replace("what_you_want_to_replace", "text_to_replace_with");
   //clear field
    driver.findElement(By.id(inputId)).clear();
   //write your new text
    driver.findElement(By.id(inputId)).sendKeys(newText);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse all text area into a string by selenium.

Then using this method to get new paragraph:

```
        public string ReplaceRow(string txtArea, int replaceLine, string textToReplace)
        {
            //Split txtArea into List String
            List<string> list = new List<string>(Regex.Split(txtArea, Environment.NewLine));
            //Replace specific line with your text
            list[replaceLine - 1] = textToReplace;
            return String.Join(Environment.NewLine, list);
        }
```

After that clear text area and send this replaced string inside. Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thank you Viet Pham. Your solution is suitable to my problem